# Windows 7/Ubuntu 12 dual boot deleted for Windows 8 installation. How to make grub rescue go away?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, grubrescue, windows-8

I had a Windows 7/Ubuntu 12 dual boot and I decided to clean install Windows 8 over them.

The problem is that after I deleted all partitions and installed windows I was getting an "Operation system not found", however after an "enter" the system will normally boot into Windows 8.

I realized that Windows did their trick and put the system (not partition anymore?!?) "tag" ([Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fKGv.png)) on my media hard drive.

After trying to fix the boot/mbr to be able to boot from my main drive the "Operation system not found" changed to the "grub rescue>" prompt. I know that I cannot use that because I have killed the grub files. Windows can still boot as long as I choose to boot from the media drive.

The question is, is there any way to move the "system", whatever it is now, to the main drive and have the PC boot from there, while making grub disappear?
And if that is possible after that, can I just make the Media drive inactive or I will have to somehow remove the "system" tag?

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info ).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Windows 8 disc, you can get to the recovery options and access a command prompt by inserting the disc and booting from it. Refer to your motherboard manual for steps to change the boot order of your hardware from within the BIOS so your CD/DVD drive boots first.

Once you have chosen to repair Windows with your installation disc, open a command prompt and type the following commands:

> bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
>
> C:
>
> cd boot
>
> attrib bcd -s -h -r
>
> ren C:\boot\bcd bcd.old
>
> bootrec /RebuildBcd

**Another Method**

> If that does not work, try these in this order:
>
> bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
>
> C:
>
> cd boot
>
> attrib bcd -s -h -r
>
> ren C:\boot\bcd bcd.old
>
> bootrec /FixMbr
>
> bootrec /FixBoot
>
> bootrec /RebuildBcd

I have had success myself with these steps in the same situation. Best of luck!

( For an image tutorial of the above, please see http://www.sysnative.com/forums/showthread.php/3894-Manually-Fix-the-Boot-Configuration-%28Windows-7-Vista%29 )

-Mike

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and sorry for my slow response.

Comment: I did use the method you describe and even though I had no errors the "starting from secondary disk boot from primary" kept appearing. At that point I realized that the whole thing was this "System Reserved" partition which was not a partition in my case.

I deliberately cleaned and deleted all partitions in both disks and did a fresh install. For some reason Win 8 prefer to put the SR partition in a different HD than the one installing into!!!

I had to remove the second drive to install all Win 8 parts in my primary.